# Getting infinite loop from a post form. Not sure if it's an htaccess issue

Tags: php, .htaccess

When submiting a $_POST['form'] I'll get a timeout error if idle for more than 8 or 9 minutes; it always changes.  This is the screen shot of the error:

[image]

This is what I got in the error logs:

```
[Sat Apr 21 20:15:00 2012] [error] [client .......] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

It can't be my scripting.  It's a pretty standard form.  Also, I'm getting this error on all 6 sites I have in shared hosting.  Here's my .htaccess file...

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On

    Options -Multiviews
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+/?)$ $1.php

    #edit forum question -- questions.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^edit/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+) edit.php?question_num=$1&question=$2 [NC]

    #edit forum question id -- questions.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^edit/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+) edit.php?question_num=$1 [NC]

    #usernames -- index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+) index.php?post=$1 [NC]
```

The problem is site wide on any post form.  If you wait to long to submit then this timeout error happens.

I don't think it's an issue with the php.ini.  I've pretty much got everything covered in it:

```
register_globals = off
allow_url_fopen = off

expose_php = Off
max_input_time = 18000
max_execution_time = 18000

;extension_dir = ./
upload_tmp_dir = ./tmp

;precision = 12

session.cache_expire = 10080
session.cookie_lifetime = 200000
session.gc_maxlifetime = 10000

memory_limit = 100M
post_max_size = 100M
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 192M
```

After checking out the .htaccess file can you see any reason for what might cause this?  Or, is it something completely different?  I should also note that I'm using cookies and no session data.

Comment: 1) *"Use '`LogLevel debug`' to get a backtrace."* - add that directive to your apache config to see what redirects are happening. 2) Change your rules to include the `L` flag (e.g. `[NC,L]`) to make sure they stop processing after the first rewrite. 3) You probably need to add an ending `$` to your rule patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an L flag in your htaccess otherwise it just loops through them infinitely -

```
# Important L flag! 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+/?)$ $1.php [L]

#edit forum question -- questions.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^edit/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+) edit.php?question_num=$1&question=$2 [NC,L]

#edit forum question id -- questions.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Important $ dollar sign next line - otherwise it matches above rule
RewriteRule ^edit/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ edit.php?question_num=$1 [NC,L]

#usernames -- index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+) index.php?post=$1 [NC,L]
```

Without the L it rewrites the rule and loops through again after the rewrite (rewriting again).

Comment: Awesome thanks!  I'm a little confused on why to use the dollar sign.  Do I use it whenever I have more than one rewrite rule for the same page? e.g. /edit/$_GET[question_num]  &&  /edit/$_GET['question_num']/$_GET['question']

Comment: What your writing there is a regular expression and the $ sign says that the string ends there. so if you have `^/example` /example will pass and so will `/example/anything` - with the dollar sign at the end, only the first would pass through as a match.